QFileDialog не отрабатывает в PyQt5
QFileDialog не отрабатывает в PyQt.
При нажатии кнопки "Ввод" выводит ошибку :

runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kononov/piton/gui.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/Kononov/piton')
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File c:\users\user\desktop\kononov\piton\gui.py:142 in openFile
file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=self,
TypeError: getOpenFileUrl(parent: Optional[QWidget] = None, caption: Optional[str] = '', directory: QUrl = QUrl(), filter: Optional[str] = '', initialFilter: Optional[str] = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0, supportedSchemes: Iterable[Optional[str]] = []): argument 'parent' has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

Не могу понять что я делаю не так?

Такое чувство что я упускаю какой-то важный момент, так как вид "накидал" в Qt Designer, а после "прогнал" в pyuic5.exe

main.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(634, 312)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile1) # работает(привязыаем к действию)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile) # работает(привязыаем к действию)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.layoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName("layoutWidget1")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_3)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem5)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem7)
        spacerItem8 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 634, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ввдите имя файла"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во частей"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчёт"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод дополнительных строк "))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начало"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конец"))
        
    # Для открытия файла используем метод getOpenFileUrl() класса
    # QFileDialog, т. к. для создания экземпляра класса
    # QMediaContent нам нужен путь к файлу, заданный в виде
    # экземпляра класса QUrl
    def openFile(self):
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=self,
            caption="Выберите звуковой файл",
            filter="Звуковые файлы (*.mp3 *.ac3)")
        
    
    def openFile1(self):
            print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



У вас всё написано в ошибке, у вас класс это просто объект (даже не QObject), а в качестве родителя Qвиджеты принимают другие Qвиджеты (или None).
Как вариант, можете передавать родителем None. Но вообще, лучше сделать отдельный класс именно виджета, а класс интерфейса не трогать (у вас он сгенерирован, как понимаю). И из класса виджета вызывать всё что нужно

спасибо сделал так :    def openFile(self):
file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent=None,
caption="Выберите звуковой файл",
filter="Звуковые файлы (*.mp3 *.ac3)")

@timob256, если это будет работать, то прекрасно. Но я вам всё же посоветую никак не изменять класс, сгенерированный для генерации интерфейса.  Как минимум, вам будет удобнее, если вся эта огромная простыня не будет мусолить глаза. Ну и опять же, для вызова функций QWidget ваш класс должен наследоваться от QWidget, чего он сейчас НЕ делает

Вы не поверите ,но в моём случае это очень сложно я не программировал уже года 2 .  и вернулся только из за обстоятельств отсуцтвия нужного мне ПО (решил написать микропрограмму для обработки текста). Даже если бы я хотел сделать правильно , я просто не знаю как сделать правильно :3 .

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   # ? , QtMultimedia


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(634, 312)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile1) # работает(привязыаем к действию)
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile) # работает(привязыаем к действию)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.layoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName("layoutWidget1")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_3)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem5)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem7)
        spacerItem8 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 634, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите URL-адрес"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во частей"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчёт"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод дополнительных строк "))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начало"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конец"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):
# ----> vvvvvvv  vv <----------------------------------------
        urlName, ok = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(
            parent=self,
            caption="Выберите звуковой файл",
            filter="Звуковые файлы (*.mp3 *.ac3)")
        if ok: 
            print("Выбран файл: ", urlName)        
            self.lineEdit.setText(
                urlName.toDisplayString(
                    QtCore.QUrl.NormalizePathSegments))
    
# ?    def openFile1(self):
# ?            print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


